# Android app wont reopen

Tags: android

I am making a game for android and after running my app on a connected device, I would press the home button to exit out of the app. But when I press on the app again, it would just be a black screen. I was wondering if I had to program the app to close? or if this is another problem? thanks!

Comment: Could you post something more, such as logcat output or code snipped. Have you overridden the `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Share some code / logcat if there's any errors.

Answer (score 0):

May be your phone is running out of memory .. Try running it using a device with higher ram or in an emulator with high config ..